# android studio unable to connect to localhost WCF service

Tags: java, c#, android, web-services, wcf

I have published my Restful WCF service in localhost using IIS. I can access this web service from any browser on my system, using url http://localhost/mobservice/MobSrv.svc

getCityList is webGet method in this service which returns city list. I am consumig this service in *Android Studio*. But in my android program it is showing error :

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://10.0.2.2/mobservice/MobSrv.svc/getCityList

My Android Code is like :

```
String serviceUrl="http://10.0.2.2/mobservice/MobSrv.svc/getCityList";
URL urlToRequest = new URL(serviceUrl);
urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)
urlToRequest.openConnection();
int statusCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
  if (statusCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED) {
      // handle unauthorized (if service requires user login)
  } else if (statusCode != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
      // handle any other errors, like 404, 500,..
  }
InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
```

statusCode returns value 404, and *urlConnection.getInputStream()* giving exception *java.io.FileNotFoundException* as described above.

ADB Integration is Enabled in android Studio.

Comment: in which line of the program it showing the exception. Could you please provide exception hierarchy message you are getting.

Comment: I have edited, with details.

Comment: @SachinSarawgi I googled and came to know that, to access localhost use  10.0.2.2, but it's not working

Comment: find your computer ip address using ipconfig or ifconfig depend on OS. Then use that IP in URL in place of 10.0.2.2 it will work. Please try and let me know.

Comment: You did not tell iwhere your Android app runs. On an emulator or on a real device? 10.0.2.2. is only good for running on an emulator.

Comment: `I am consumig this service in Android Studio`. Dont think so. You will consume it in an Android app.

Answer (score 1):

Find your computer IP address using ipconfig for Windows and ifconfig for Linux. It will be shown as IPv4 address.

Then in the request URL use that IP address in place of 10.0.2.2.

> http://computer_ip_address/mobservice/MobSrv.svc/getCityList